# Progress Bar on drag JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, timeline

EDIT:I work with JS UI Slider and I want for each year that value to increase with 0,62% Some ideas? How I can do it?

```
<script> $( function() {
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 37,
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) ); } ); </script>
```

**IMAGE HIER**

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929179/js-ui-slider-change-to-value-precent

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTML element called `<input type="range">`. You can style it with CSS although browser implementations differ greatly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range