# JS UI Slider / change to value (- precent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I use JS UI Slider to make something like timeline. I want, when the year value increase with 1 - my output value to reduce with 0,662%. Some ideas? How I can do it?

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 733131,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value * (1 - 0.66 / 100));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

Comment: `2,4` in your JS will be causing a syntax error: https://jsfiddle.net/028e54kk/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oddly, it seems to work in the SO snippets. I'm unsure why, but it was a neat exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var numAnimalsToday = 733131;
  $("#slider-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 2018,
    min: 2018,
    max: 2218,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var animalsLost = numAnimalsToday * ((ui.value - 2018) * 0.00662);

      $("#year").val(ui.value);
      $("#amount").val(numAnimalsToday - animalsLost);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="year" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

I've changed the `value` to be the current year, `max` to be year 2218, added the `step` option to increment only by whole numbers, added a `year` div to display the year, and changed the `amount` div output to be the difference in years times `0.00662` deducted from the original amount of animals.

Comment: not really, when you drag to right (not left),  output will be reduce with 0.0662% (- 0.662%)

Comment: Example now 2018 - output 733131, but 2019 - output is 728 277.67 (-0.662%)

Comment: So you want the output to be 733131 for 2018? How does that equate to `-0.662%`?

Comment: you have timeline from 2018 to 2218 (year) - 2018 year the output is 733131 (animals), but 2019 you have for output 728277,67 animals (-0.662%) and etc. Every year we lost 0,662% animals

Comment: @Med.Mass I understand now, hopefully this solution better suits your needs.